# Modbus TCP / serial forwarder doesn't forward the correct message

Tags: modbus, pymodbus

I am trying to control an Airzone device which has a Modbus interface from a remote computer. To do so I have connect a raspberry pi to the Modbus interface, using a USB to Modbus adapter.

I have started a forwarder server in the RPi using pymodbus. The code for the forwarder is the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Pymodbus synchronous forwarder.

This is a repeater or converter and an example of just how powerful datastore is.

It consist of a server (any comm) and a client (any comm), functionality:

a) server receives a read/write request from external client:

    - client sends a new read/write request to target server
    - client receives response and updates the datastore
    - server sends new response to external client

Both server and client are tcp based, but it can be easily modified to any server/client
(see client_sync.py and server_sync.py for other communication types)

**WARNING** This example is a simple solution, that do only forward data (read/write) requests.
"""
import asyncio
import logging

from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.datastore.remote import RemoteSlaveContext
from pymodbus.server import StartAsyncTcpServer


_logger = logging.getLogger()



async def run_forwarder():
    """Run forwarder setup."""
    client = ModbusSerialClient(
        port="/dev/ttyUSB0",
        baudrate=19200,
        parity='E',
        method="rut"
    )
    client.connect()
    assert client.connected
    # If required to communicate with a specified client use slave=<slave_id>
    # in RemoteSlaveContext
    # For e.g to forward the requests to slave with slave address 1 use
    # store = RemoteSlaveContext(client, slave=1)
    store = RemoteSlaveContext(client, slave=1)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

    await StartAsyncTcpServer(context=context, address=("0.0.0.0", 5020))
    # loop forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_forwarder())
```

On the remote computer I am just creating a ModbusTcpClient and connecting to the server. I can connect without problem and I write to a register using

```
client = ModbusTcpClient("192.168.1.75", port=5020)
client.connect()
client.write_register(address=0x00, value=1)
```

That starts my airconditioner, so its working fine. However, when I tri to shutdown the air conditioner using

```
client.write_register(address=0x00, value=0)
```

it doesn't work.

To verify everything was okay, I stopped the server and created a ModbusSerialClient alone directly in the RPi, and perform the same write operation on the register, which correctly turns off the air conditioner, so the issue is somewhere in how I am creating the server

I am completely new to Modbus and just tried to follow Pymodbus documentation for this. Any hitns on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your shutdown command looks wrong - shouldn't it be `client.write_register(address=0x00, value=0)`?

Comment: That was a typo, I edit the question

Comment: I can't see an obvious issue. Perhaps try using another tool (e.g. [modpoll](https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html)) just to confirm the issue is with the repeater (try on off on off).

Comment: Could you briefly explain how to use modpoll? Do I have to install it in the RPi? Thanks

Comment: It's just an app that makes modbus requests (alternatives are mbpoll and qmodmaster). Install one of these on your "remote computer" and send the on/off requests (want to eliminate your python client as a possible cause).

Comment: So I leave the Tcp server running on the Rpi and perform the requests using the suggested app, right?

Comment: Yes - just to confirm the issue is with the software on the pi. Try sending multiple commands (e.g. manually turn off the send on command again).

Comment: I am not sure I understand how to write to register 0. I am trying the following command with modpoll `/modpoll -p 5020 -r 0 192.168.1.75 1`, but says `Invalid reference`

Comment: I have managed to send alternate pulses of on/off to the server and still fails, so its clear there is something wrong on the server side

Comment: So ive managed to workaround the issue by installing the version 2 of pymodbus, instead of version 3.